# Relacionamento de registros de uma tabela com ela mesma

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando montar uma estrutura de arvore genealogica, porem ainda não consigo relacionar e deixar preparado para que o while percorra a tabela inteira e estruture a arvore de forma infinita, uma vez que a pessoa pode ter 'x' filhos.

Então a tabela está

```
|ID  | Nome | IdPai |
|1   | Zé   |  NULL |
|2   | Joao | 1     |
|3   | Maria| 1     |
```

Então, eu consigo para poucos niveis colocar um while dentro de um while, porém, creio que exista uma forma mais fácil de garantir que o while percorra todo a tabela.

Alguma Sugestão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso você precisa fazer uma função recursiva. Função recursiva é aquela que pode fazer uma chamada a ela mesmo.

Como você não colocou seu código, vou colocar um exemplo de forma bem abstrata:

```
function getArvore($id, $count, $conn) {
    if ((!isset($count)) || ($count = null)) {
        $count = 1;
    }

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT Nome FROM sua_tabela WHERE ID = :id");
    $query->execute(array("id" => $id));
    $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (count($rows) > 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            echo "-";
        }
        echo $rows[0]["Nome"]."<br />";
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM sua_tabela WHERE IdPai = :id");
        $query->execute(array("id" => $id));
        $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            getArvore($row["id"], $count + 1, $conn);
        }
    }
}

$conn = new PDO(
        'mysql:host='.$seu_host.'; dbname='.$seu_banco,
        $seu_usuario,
        $sua_senha,
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
        )
);

getArvore(1, 1, $conn);
```

A partir deste exemplo você pode fazer exatamente o que você precisa.

Comment: Por algum motivo ele me diz que existem muitas conexões para esse arquivo...

Comment: Tenta com a edição que eu fiz

Comment: Caramba... O poder disso é animal!